# How to remove all color from selected text (resulting in transparent text) perfectly?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

I want an image with some text, such that the background color of the image is white, while the text should transparent.

The twist here is that the font I am using does not satisfy my needs, and I have to apply "transform" (using Ctrl+T) after I write using the "Horizontal Type Mask Tool" and to sort of spread the text horizontally (so that the letters become a bit less condensed).

**What I tried:**

1. I created a new file with white background
2. Wrote the text on it using the Horizontal Type Mask Tool
3. Added a color to it (because without this when I try to apply the
   Transform, it complains that the selected area is empty) using the
   Paint Bucket tool
4. Applied the Transform.
5. The text was still selected. So pressing `Del` deleted everything
   from the selected text.

**But when I deselected it, the result was very ugly. There is an ugly black border sort of a thing around the text.**

I have also tried using the *Background Eraser Tool* but that doesn't do it perfectly either. So I conclude my approach for getting what I want was not good. **So my question is that what is the best way to do this?**

[image]

Comment: Don't press delete, make a mask instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create a text layer with your text.
2. Create a white-filled layer
3. <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>-click the text layer thumbnail in the
   **Layers Panel**
4. Highlight the white layer and click the **New Mask** icon at the
   bottom of the **Layers Panel**.
5. Invert the layer mask (`Image > Adjustments > Invert`)
6. Turn off visibility for the text layer.

You can then unlink the mask with its layer and freely transform the mask if needed.

[image]

<sub>(White looks grey due to the reduced color palette of the animation.)</sub>