# How to drill/cut a solid, using a text as a template?

Tags: text, adobe-after-effects, drop-shadow

Imagine a situation where I have a solid and a text.

I would like the content of the text to be taken subtracted from the solid behind it.

**Text and solid (I did it in GIMP, which is the program I know how to do):**

[image]

**By merging and removing the letters I get the result I want (in GIMP):**

[image]

It turns out that I would like to know how to do this directly in Adobe After Effects, as I intend to do this with several texts (it would be laborious to have to keep using both tools).

**To apply the drop shadow to the punched/cut solid:**

[image]

---

I apologize if at any point the question was confused. I still don't know the technical terms and a lot is lost in the translation I do (I'm not an English speaker). Feel free to edit the question to make it clearer to understand.

Comment: You want to make a mask? Easiest would just be to use a intensity mask

Comment: @joojaa Basically! I googled the term you were talking about and it looks like it's exactly that.

Comment: I don't know AE.. but Photoshop: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50890/how-to-remove-all-color-from-selected-text-resulting-in-transparent-text-perfe

Comment: @Scott It would be exactly that, I know how to do this in Photoshop and GIMP, but I would like to do it directly in After Effects.

Comment: Knowing the name of the terms, I think searching a video will be much easier. Part of the problem I had is because I didn't know the name of the technique I wanted to do. Thanks!